# Flutter Dart: RegEx to extract URLs from a String

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

This is my string:

```
    window.urlVideo = 'https://node34.vidstreamcdn.com/hls/5d59908aea5aa101a054dec2a1cd3aff/5d59908aea5aa101a054dec2a1cd3aff.playlist.m3u8';
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myVideo");
var countplayer = 1;
var countcheck = 0;
playerInstance.setup({
    sources: [{
        "file": urlVideo
    }],
    tracks: [{
        file: "https://cache.cdnfile.info/images/13f9ddcaf2d83d846056ec44b0f1366d/12.vtt",
        kind: "thumbnails"
    }],
    image: "https://cache.cdnfile.info/images/13f9ddcaf2d83d846056ec44b0f1366d/12_cover.jpg",
});

function changeLink() {
    window.location = "//vidstreaming.io/load.php?id=MTM0OTgz&title=Mairimashita%21+Iruma-kun+Episode+12";
}
window.shouldChangeLink = function () {
    window.location = "//vidstreaming.io/load.php?id=MTM0OTgz&title=Mairimashita%21+Iruma-kun+Episode+12";
}
```

I am using flutter dart.

How can I get window.urlVideo URL link and image URL link and .vtt file link?

Or

How can I get a list of URLs from a String?
I tried finding a way with and without using RegEx but I couldn't.

Any help is apreciated

Comment: You say you are using Flutter/Dart but the code you shared is Javascript.

Comment: @JoãoSoares That is not the code. It is the value of the string. I want to scrape the urls from this string.

Comment: So your string is all this javascript code and you want to extract 3 URLs from it? Are you scrapping a web page? Surely there is a better way for you to obtain these urls without having to do this from your Flutter App.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting just the *https?* and *ftp* url's that are  in quotes is this :

`r"([\"'])\s*((?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\u00a1-\uffff]+-?)*[a-zA-Z0-9\u00a1-\uffff]+)(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\u00a1-\uffff]+-?)*[a-zA-Z0-9\u00a1-\uffff]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/(?:(?!\1|\s)[\S\s])*)?)\s*\1"`

Where the Url is captured in group 2.

https://regex101.com/r/UPmLBl/1

Answer (score 38):

This may not be the complete regex, but this worked for me for randomly picked links:

```
void main() {
  final text = """My website url: https://blasanka.github.io/
Google search using: www.google.com, social media is facebook.com, http://example.com/method?param=flutter
stackoverflow.com is my greatest website. DartPad share: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/wiki/Sharing-Guide see this example and edit it here https://dartpad.dev/3d547fa15849f9794b7dbb8627499b00""";

  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r'(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?[\w/\-?=%.]+\.[\w/\-?=%.]+');
  Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(text);

  matches.forEach((match) {
    print(text.substring(match.start, match.end));
  });
}
```

Result:

```
https://blasanka.github.io/
www.google.com
facebook.com
http://example.com/method?param=flutter
stackoverflow.com
https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/wiki/Sharing-Guide
https://dartpad.dev/3d547fa15849f9794b7dbb8627499b00
```

Play with it here: https://dartpad.dev/3d547fa15849f9794b7dbb8627499b00

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer!

Comment: I have a String `Made by https://cretezy.com` and Expected output: `Made by <a href="https://cretezy.com">https://cretezy.com</a>`. Kindly suggest me how can we do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not worked for me. I have a string which has `https://support.google.com/firebase?authuser=0#topic=6399725` url and your solution converts it to like `https://support.google.com/firebase?authuser=0` ignoring hash and further text string `#topic=6399725`. Kindly suggest how can we solve it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kamlesh you can add any special char you want to the reg expression as mentioned in above comments. Based on the special char you may have to use escape character

Comment: Thanks @Blasanka for your reply. This solution worked perfectly for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59445736/10329023

Comment: It also extract multi dots also. like goo... this.is

Answer (score 11):

Try this,

```
final urlRegExp = new RegExp(
    r"((https?:www\.)|(https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)?");
final urlMatches = urlRegExp.allMatches(text);
List<String> urls = urlMatches.map(
        (urlMatch) => text.substring(urlMatch.start, urlMatch.end))
    .toList();
urls.forEach((x) => print(x));
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear, your solution worked for me perfectly :)

Answer (score 5):

Much safer to use a library like [linkify](https://pub.dev/packages/linkify) instead of rolling your own regex.

```dart
/// Attempts to extract link from a string.
///
/// If no link is found, then return null.
String extractLink(String input) {
  var elements = linkify(input,
      options: LinkifyOptions(
        humanize: false,
      ));
  for (var e in elements) {
    if (e is LinkableElement) {
      return e.url;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Linkify uses the following regex right now: `r'^(.*?)((?:https?:\/\/|www\.)[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*)'`. Based on my testing at `https://regexr.com/3e6m0`, this matches `https://google..............totallyrealurl,ofcourse!?`