# How to extract substring starting from index of particular character upto the index of some other character from given string?

Tags: string, flutter, oop, dart, substring

Suppose, i have a string str = "**lorem ipsum src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HyvFqW7xE1c" lorem ipsum**". i want to extract substring **https://www.youtube.com/embed/HyvFqW7xE1c** which is actually a url. I can extract index of "**h**" which is starting index of the required url by using **indexOf()** method. But how can i extract complete url where length is url is not fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RegExp()` and `Iterable<RegExpMatch>` to get URL from string.

```
  var text = """lorem ipsum src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" lorem 
  ipsum""";
  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r'(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?[\w/\-?=%.]+\.[\w/\-?=%.]+');
  Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(text);

  matches.forEach((match) {
    print(text.substring(match.start, match.end));
  });
```

Resource [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59445257/11855654)

Comment: i tried accessing substring starting from www. but i got //www.

Comment: No, I don't think you will get `//` even when you start the URL with `www.`.